# Create a simple drawing tool in HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, draw, floor

I'm working on this project where I'd like to give my user the possibility to draw a simple floor plan by rooms, and then stock it with maybe some metadata (like room names).

I see it like that:
- you click on "add a new room"
- you draw a rectangle on the screen (or maybe another simple shape)
- you give it a name

I'd like to new what's the best (and the simplest) language to use to create that kind of tool. HTML5+jQuery? Flash? Is there any existing tool/plugin that could do the trick?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd probably say Flash is what you want.  "Simple" shapes are not easy to draw with just JavaScript (diamonds or circles), while this is easily achieved through Flash.  You could use [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).  HTML5 provides `<canvas>` that allows you to draw shapes, but you would need to have custom code that draws diamonds, rhombuses, etc.

Comment: @vinceh: SVG is supported by IE9, and the Raphael SVG/JavaScript library have VML for older versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would probably be in HTML5 with a canvas tag. You could use jquery to get mouse events.

If you have access and experience with Flash though, that will probably be your best bet as users are more likely to have flash than html5.

If you do use html5, heres some great help documents

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery and the html5 canvas element, but I would have the user draw the shapes using straight lines. They click the line image, select two points and jQuery draws the line. Having the shapes drawn in jQuery will allow you to store them, to allow you to easily add the metadata, and package the data serialised in a db for future use, or store as an image, whatever you wish.